# Problems with menu OffScreen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an off canvas menu and he's always on the screen, but my main div is above him, só, when i click on the button, the main swipe to right and then u can see the menu, OK? OK. But i have 3 problems:

1. When the menu is activated the page automaticly scrolls to the top, but it should only disable the scroll.
2. When I close the menu, my body keeps not scrolling, even if I change it via Jquery
3. The links of the menu doesn't work.

I've tried to use `TranslateX()`, but It doesn't show the menu. Where I'm Wrong?

I'm using the menu of this website as inspiration, http://www.x-apps.com.br/ and that's my website https://tiagosilveiraa.github.io/

```js
var menu = false;
$('#hamburguer').click(function() {
    if (menu === false) {
      mostraCanvas();
    } else {
      escondeCanvas();
    }
});

function escondeCanvas() {
    $("#main").css("padding-left", "0");
    $("html, body").css("overflow", "auto");

    menu = false;
}

function mostraCanvas() {
  $("#main").css("padding-left", "50vw");
  $("html, body").css("overflow", "hidden");
  menu = true;
}

$('.off-item').click(function() {
    escondeCanvas();
});
```

```css
.off-canvas{
  padding-top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #292929;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50vw;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: left;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
}
#main{
  z-index: 9999;
  margin: 0 !important;
  transition: all .2s linear;
  -webkit-transition: padding .2s linear;
  -moz-transition: padding .2s linear;
  -o-transition: padding .2s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
      <div class="topo" id="topo">
      <button id="hamburguer"><h1><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger blue btn-nav"></span></h1><button>
    </div>
      <nav class="navbar" id="navbar">
         <ul>
            <a href="#banner" id="linkbanner">
               <li class="nav-item">
                  <h2>Inicio</h2>
               </li>
            </a>
            <a href="#sobremim">
               <li class="nav-item">
                  <h2>Sobre Mim</h2>
               </li>
            </a>
            <a href="#portfolio">
               <li class="nav-item">
                  <h2>Portfólio</h2>
               </li>
            </a>
            <a href="#habilidades">
               <li class="nav-item">
                  <h2>Habilidades</h2>
               </li>
            </a>
            <a href="#contato">
               <li class="nav-item">
                  <h2>Contato</h2>
               </li>
            </a>
         </ul>
      </nav>
     ...body stuff here...  
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. I refactored the html because a tag cannot be inside ul. I changed also the overflow into overflow-x to avoid the scroll problem. I hope it helps.

```js
var menu = false;
$('#hamburguer').click(function() {
    if (menu === false) {
      mostraCanvas();
    } else {
      escondeCanvas();
    }
});

function escondeCanvas() {
    $("#main").css("padding-left", "0");
    $("body").css("overflow-x", "");

    menu = false;
}

function mostraCanvas() {
  $("#main").css("padding-left", "50vw");
  $("body").css("overflow-x", "hidden");
  menu = true;
}

$('.off-item').click(function() {
    escondeCanvas();
});
```

```css
.off-canvas{
  padding-top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #292929;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50vw;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: left;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
}
#main{
  z-index: 9999;
  margin: 0 !important;
  transition: all .2s linear;
  -webkit-transition: padding .2s linear;
  -moz-transition: padding .2s linear;
  -o-transition: padding .2s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
      <div class="topo" id="topo">
      <button id="hamburguer"><h1><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger blue btn-nav"></span></h1><button>
    </div>
      <nav class="navbar" id="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#banner" id="linkbanner">
              <h2>Inicio</h2>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#sobremim">
              <h2>Sobre Mim</h2>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#portfolio">
              <h2>Portfólio</h2>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#habilidades">
              <h2>Habilidades</h2>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#contato">
              <h2>Contato</h2>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
     ...body stuff here...  
  </div>
```

Comment: At the same time that it worked, it doesn't. When the menu is activated and I scroll, theres a space between the bottom os the menu and the rest of the page: http://prntscr.com/fgs9ua

Comment: Looks funny, but in landscape mode it works perfectly.

Comment: It depends on your layout. If you want a full height column you will need a css table or flexbox based layout. But it is hard to suggest you further without a test page, the screen capture is not enough.

Comment: If want, U can see all my CSS using the developer tools or on my Github, I'm using bootstrap grids, how can I implement the layout that you said on him?